# SQL adding new column as arbitrary calculated field (Postgres / redshift)

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to add new calculated fields (columns) to a table.

If using python with pandas, I could do something like this:

```
df['new_field'] = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(func, axis=1)
```

Let's assume `func` is defined as a UDF in SQL that returns a bool, how can I create a new column by applying that to other columns in my table? I tried this without success:

```
alter table my_table
add column new_field bool default null;
update my_table set new_field = (select func(col1, col2) from my_table);
```

This is wrong since update expects a single value or where clauses. I have also tried storing the calculated field in new tables but I have no common key to merge them on so the sort order gets messed up.

Right now the best solution I can think of is to do

```
create table my_table_2 as (select *, func(col1, col2) as new_field from table);
```

but that does not seem very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just call it:

```
update my_table
     set new_field = func(col1, col2) ;
```

No additional `select` is needed, unless it happens to be an aggregation function.